# turned off display on start up and no grub

Tags: graphic-drivers, grub, display

I've done a clean install of Elementary Freya for the first time and picked full disk encryption. Everything seemed fine until I was required to restart the PC. There was no grub selection screen after the BIOS and instead I was presented with a turned off display(not black screen just turned off with no back-light) until I pressed one of the arrow keys when the display turned on and a "Passphrase" input was requested. After entering the passphrase the system appears to be loading some stuffs and then you go to the login screen.

Is this the expected behavior? I am new to elementary and had just some experience with a few other linux distros in the past. but it always loaded into grub and there was never a turned off display.

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: I don't know what happened but now it suddenly started to show the GRUB selection menu and Elementary graphic + passphrase box. previously it was just a command like prompt. I guess it is fixed?

Comment: The boot screen with the elementary logo and animation fails to load sometimes until you press an arrow key. I think this should be a bug.